# plot the graph using different Excel files

Tags: excel, qt, matlab, java

I have some data stored in different **Microsoft Excel Worksheet (.xlsx)** .
Now i want to ploat a graph by using these data (which are in different .xlsx) files.
 How can i do this ? 
means which **language** or **platform** i should use or any other help related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab has the built-in function [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html) which parses data from Excel files. Depending on how the files are organized, writing some code to read them all should be easy, and concatenating the matrices of data and plotting them is also pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java API's to create graph if you are familiar with java. You can use Apache POI or jfreechart or openxmlformats(api provided by apache).

Answer (score 0):

if you use saveAs to save them as CSV files, you can read them in very easily to Java and split the values with String.split(","). If you want to keep them as .xlsx files, [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) might be able to help, though personally I've never used it. As for graphing, I'd recommend [Javaplot/gnuplot](http://gnujavaplot.sourceforge.net/JavaPlot/About.html), [Jzy3D](http://www.jzy3d.org/), or [JMathPlot](http://code.google.com/p/jmathplot/) depending on what you want to graph. They're free and relatively easy to use.